# Ruby: How do I convert from UNIX struct tm?

Tags: ruby, unix, time

I'm trying to work with Linux's RTC in Ruby. The RTC driver via ioctl returns soemthing very similar to `struct tm`, as found in the [standard `time.h` file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/time.h.html). Alas, I cannot find a standard Ruby method that understands this structure (month number is 0-based, year is 1900-based). Short of some trivial coding, is there a standard library/object in Ruby that can convert a tm struct/array into a Time object?

The current solution is:

```
rtctm_raw=rtc.unpack("iiiiii")   # see rtc(4) or time.h
rtctm=[ *rtctm_raw, 0,0,0,0 ]
rtctm[4]+=1
rtctm[5]+=1900
rtc_values=Time.gm(*rtctm)
```

But I consider this ugly, since one would think Ruby's "gm" and "mktime" calls mirror the POSIX counterparts. But they don't. If such calls are available, I would prefer to use them.

Comment: Did you try something? What's wrong with some piece of trivial coding?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to convert... is it a string?

Comment: @Kris done. See update.

Comment: @EricDuminil. It's not clear why the "Ruby" way purposefully deviates from the "POSIX/IEEE" way while maintaining same function names. Maybe there was some other module I should use or some mode to switch.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an offset, just apply it before creating a `Time` instance :

```
tm_struct = {
  tm_year: 117,
  tm_mon: 2,
  tm_mday: 7,
  tm_hour: 14,
  tm_min: 32,
  tm_sec: 30
} 

puts Time.local(
  tm_struct[:tm_year] + 1900, 
  tm_struct[:tm_mon] + 1,
  *tm_struct.values_at(:tm_mday, :tm_hour, :tm_min, :tm_sec)
) 
#=> 2017-03-07 14:32:30 +0100
```